# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined - Target to es6

Tags: build, typescript, phantomjs, ecmascript-6, karma-jasmine

i am getting the `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` in `jasmine` unit test with `karma`.

this my `karma.conf.js` file.

`tsconfig.json` - target `"target": "es6"`

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: './',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'dist/dev/**/*.js', included: false, watched: true },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js', included: false, watched: false }, // PhantomJS2 (and possibly others) might require it
      'dist/**/*.spec.js',
    ],
    proxies: { },
    exclude: [    ],
    preprocessors: {
      'dist/**/!(*spec).js': ['coverage']
    },
    reporters: ['mocha', 'coverage'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: [
      'PhantomJS',
      'Chrome'
    ],
    singleRun: false,
    client: {    }
  });
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Recommend compiling your code with additionally `--module commonjs` and using a karma plugin that understands commonjs i.e. https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-commonjs

Comment: I am getting the following error ... 
`PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'class'
  at e:/Natarajan/Git/mission/mission.api/dist/dev/appsettings.js:2`

Comment: `Use of reserved word 'class' a` it seems PhantomJS *doesn't support ES6*. Please change `target` to `es5` 

Comment: we are using `async` and `await` in `es6`. so  I can not change the target to `es5`.